# visualizing RDF query result

Tags: .net, data-visualization, semantic-web, graph-algorithm

My SPARQL Query returns a set of results, I want to visualize the Query results using an RDF Visualization algorithm, such that the results are related together and also I retrieve some more info about it.

Example:

if My domain is Movie industry, and I query about all movies directed by James Cameron, I get about 10 or 11 results, something like,

```
 'The Terminator'
 'Rambo: First Blood Part II'
 'Aliens'
 'The Abyss'
 'Terminator 2: Judgment Day '
 'True Lies'
 'Titanic'
 'Avatar'
```

I want to make a visualized graph between all the results, showing the main relation "directed by James cameron" and also searching for some other relation through semantic web, try something like this: 
[image]

The above result came from [relFinder](http://www.visualdataweb.org/relfinder/relfinder.php) where the Entities we compared between are the movies themselves,note that relFinder is semanticWeb-Based.

I am interested on similar algorithms to Generate Queries based on some algorithms to retrieve results to relate to the original Query to give more detailed relations

I also want to know if there's any dotNet libraries to facilitate the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of .Net libraries for RDF and SPARQL that will let you do the querying part but you'll need to find a visualization library that suits your needs and combine the two.

In terms of RDF/SPARQL libraries for .Net you have the choice of the following:

- [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org) - This is my preference but then I am the lead developer ;-)
- [SemWeb.Net](http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/) - No longer actively maintained (as of 2009) and no SPARQL 1.1 support
- [Intellidimension SemanticsSDK](http://www.intellidimension.com/products/semantics-platform/) - Primarily a commercial product, free edition has limited features and restrictive license

I'm not a visualization expert so you'd have to go research that yourself

Comment: yea, I'm already using dotNetRDF for the querying part (thank u :) ), My problem is with the algorithm to generate more related queries to the original queries be able to make a graph like the one in the example above.

Comment: Well the relfinder source code is available at http://code.google.com/p/relfinder/ - have you tried looking at their source code to see how they decide what queries to generate?

Comment: In particular http://code.google.com/p/relfinder/source/browse/trunk/src/connection/SPARQLQueryBuilder.as appears to be the code you'll be most interested in