# Graph Traversing algorithms in Semantic web

Tags: graph, semantic-web, graph-algorithm, freebase, dbpedia

I am asking about Algorithms that would be useful in Querying the Semantic web DB to get all the related RDFs to an original Object.

i.e If the original Object is the movie `"inception"`, I want an algorithm to build queries to get the RDFs of the cast of the movie, the studio, the country ....etc so that I can build a relationship graph.

The most close example is the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147097/visualizing-rdf-query-result) , Especially [this class](http://code.google.com/p/relfinder/source/browse/trunk/src/connection/SPARQLQueryBuilder.as) , I wan similar algorithms or maybe titles to search in order to produce such an algorithm, I am thinking maybe some modifications on graph traversing algorithms can work, but I'm not sure.

NOTE: My project is in ASP.NET. So, it would help to use Exisiting .NET libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a simple [breadth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to get all the objects that are a certain distance away from a given node.

You'll need to know something about the schema because some neighboring nodes are more meaningful than others. For example, in Freebase, we have [intermediate nodes](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Cvt) that [link a film to an actor and a role](http://www.freebase.com/schema/film/performance). You need to know to go 2-ply deep to get at the actor and the role because just saying that the film is related to the intermediate nodes is not very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at "[property paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/)"?

> Property Paths give a more succinct way to write parts of basic graph
>   patterns and also extend matching of triple pattern to arbitrary
>   length paths. Property paths do not invalidate or change any existing
>   SPARQL query.

Triple stores and SPARQL engines such as [OWLIM](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/whats-new) and [AllegroGraph](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/current/sparql-1.1-release-notes.html) support them.